# Is it possible to create a list that might look for meeting one of a few specified options?

Tags: python, list

Are you able to give a value (I would be using an inputted value), and if it is any one of multiple given values, it would meet the "if" statement's criteria. I realize that I could use multiple "if" statements, but multiple "if" statements that all carry out the same function would be cluttered.

```
tested_value = 1  
if tested_value is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  
    print("tested_value is an integer between 1 and 5")  
else  
    print("tested_value is not an integer between 1 and 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python keyword is `in`, like this:

```
tested_value = 1
if tested_value in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    print("tested_value is an integer between 1 and 5")
else:
    print("tested_value is not an integer between 1 and 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

in python you can check ranges like this:

```
tested_value = 1  
if 1 <= tested_value <= 5:
    print("tested_value is an integer between 1 and 5")  
else:
    print("tested_value is not an integer between 1 and 5")
```

but if you want to check if its in a list check Adrians answer.

However, checking the range like above will match floats that are between 1 and 5 as well as ints.